# how to store and read files in ldap server using jndi?

Tags: ldap, jndi, openldap

Can we store files (`.txt` and `.xml` files) on an ldap server? Is there any java sample client to write and read a file in an ldap server?

Answer (score 1):

> how to store and read files in ldap server using jndi?

You can't.

> Can we store files (.txt and .xml files) on an ldap server?

No.

> Is there any java sample client to write and read a file in an ldap server?

No.

*Unless,* in a *specific object class*, you can find a suitable binary-valued attribute, such as `userCertificate.`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I read that its possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746763/how-to-store-a-file-in-ldap. But i didnt understand how to do the same? there is no links or samples given. please provode any inputs you have.

Comment: @user2408846 I agree with the posters at your link. LDAP isn't suitable for this.

Comment: @user2408846 Don't do that if you didn't understand the answers in the linked question.